# Service name and icon not showing in the Volume Mixer. Why?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm making a windows service that continuously plays an embedded audio file in the background. I was able to make it successfully but for some reason, the name and the icon of the application is not showing in the Volume Mixer. It's just showing as "Name Not Available" as you can see in the picture below. Using the exact same code and settings but as a normal Windows Application (not a service) the icon and name shows up correctly. This only happens when it's built as a service. Why is that? How can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

[image: Volume Mixer]

Comment: My first thought is that this is because your service is running under different account than the other apps. Usually as local system. Try changing the account that your service is using and see what happens

Comment: Hello there! Thanks for the response. That's what I thought. I tried running it with the local account I was logged into but it was the same. Any other ideas?